# How can we check database in android

Tags: android, database

I Switch to the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse there are a DATA folder in File Explorer but data folder does not open next. so I unable to view the database. so please help me. to view the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can only view the data/data folder on an emulator or if you root your device and alter the permissions of those folders manually.

Comment: I SUGGEST using an emulator. But, if you MUST you a real deive: You must root your device (instructions to root are different for every device) first. Then, there are many ways to change permissions. You could use adb shell and use the "chmod" command, or just an app such as: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree